# How do I remove a list phrases from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, underscore.js

I want to check a string for a list of phrases. If those phrases exist I want to remove them and return a new string.

```
For Example:
String: Lower Dens - Propagation (Official Music Video)
Result: Lower Dens - Propagation
```

This is what I have so far, but it does not work. This would work for single words, but not phrases. I am using underscore for the each loop, but I am open to any solution.

```
formatVideoTitle = function(videoTitle){
    var phrases = [
        '(Official Music Video)',
        '(Official Video)',
        '(Music Video)'
    ],
    newVideoTitle = videoTitle;

    _.each(phrases, function(phrase){
        newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
    });

    return newVideoTitle;
};
```

Comment: What javascript libraries do you have loaded? I don't recognize '_.each'

Comment: That's `underscore`.

Comment: Do you see errors in javascript console?

Comment: Do you have any example strings to show us (both the original and the amended ('before'/'after') versions)? From the look of it you want to remove `(<string of characters> Video)` from everything?

Comment: I'm not following what you are trying to accomplish. Could you post a little more information about what the desired inputs/outputs would look like?

Comment: What version of 'underscore.js' are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
formatVideoTitle = function(videoTitle){
    var phrases = [
        '(Official Music Video)',
        '(Official Video)',
        '(Music Video)'
    ],
    newVideoTitle = videoTitle;

    _.each(phrases, function(phrase){
        newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
    });

    return newVideoTitle;
};
```

Edit: The change is

```
newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
```

'replace' returns the result of the operation, you you'll need to pass it back.  Also beware that this will only match the first occurance of that string, if the phrase appears multiple times then you'll need to use regex to replace all instances.

Edit 2: Example of use of regex to replace all instances:

```
newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(new RegExp(phrase, 'g'), '');
```

Comment: Answer a question with an answer, not another question. I suggest explaining the difference between your version and his and explaining why his is wrong and your's is right.

Answer (score 1):

set newVideoTitle to the result of the replace operation it works.  I would make a jsfiddle but am too lazy to include underscore.

[heres a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxea8vLo/1/)

```
formatVideoTitle = function(videoTitle){
    var phrases = [
        '(Official Music Video)',
        '(Official Video)',
        '(Music Video)'
    ],
    newVideoTitle = videoTitle;

    _.each(phrases, function(phrase){
        newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
    });

    return newVideoTitle;
};
```

Comment: whoops updated the fiddle to call the function.  also mine isn't some objects method like yours appears to be so you'll have to adjust that.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` returns a value, so you need to assign the replaced variable to a new variable (or the same one):

```
_.each(phrases, function(phrase) {
  newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Le5spuy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the replace statement. If you assign the result to newVideoTitle than it will work.

```
newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(phrase, '');
```

Comment: Sorry for this duplication, In an attempt to earn my first points, I also need to respond quicker than the others. Any how, you have now at least the correct answer from three independent sources :-)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of "replaceAll" in JavaScript, I like to use "split/join".

```
formatVideoTitle = function(videoTitle){
    ...
    _.each(phrases, function(phrase){
        newVideoTitle.split(phrase).join('');
    });

    return newVideoTitle;
};
```

If you know that the phrase is always at the back of the string, you could also use:

```
formatVideoTitle = function(videoTitle){
    ...
    _.each(phrases, function(phrase){
        newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.slice(0, newVideoTitle.indexOf(phrase));
    });

    return newVideoTitle;
};
```

Comment: Bad solution to the 'replaceAll' problem. Use Regular expression solution...

newVideoTitle = newVideoTitle.replace(new RegExp(phrase, 'g'), '');

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not using underscore for this, JavaScript has a relatively easy means of achieving the same with regular expressions (though there's a little complexity in the creation of that regular expression):

```
formatVideoTitle = function (title) {
    var phrases = [
        '(Official Music Video)',
        '(Official Video)',
        '(Music Video)'],
    // creating Regular Expression object, by joining the phrases together with '|'
    // characters (an 'OR' relationship) to create a string, prefacing the '(' and ')'
    // characters with a double escape (to escape them in the created RegExp), and
    // wrapping that created string in '(' and ')' to create a matching group:
        reg = new RegExp('(' + phrases.join('|').replace(/(\(|\))/g, function(a){
            return '\\' + a;
        }) + ')', 'gi');
    // returning the amended title:
    return title.replace(reg, '');
}

console.log(formatVideoTitle("Lower Dens - Propagation (Official Music Video)"));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q6p9n404/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).